# Data bind click even pass current object to parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, binding

I am looping through objects and I want to send only current object when clicked.

```html
<div class="box" data-bind="foreach: contacts">
                <div class="contact LightGray-background">
                    <div class="contactType">
                        <label data-bind="text: contactLabel"></label>
                        <label style="font-size:smaller" data-bind="text:contactRole"></label>
                        <img class="hasInfoPopup" data-bind="click: $root.editContact($root)"
                             data-info="Edit Contact" src="~/images/plus-inverted-large.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;float:right" />
</div>
```

editContact() above is receiving all object values instead of only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `editContact` in your binding. That means knockout will call it once (passing `$root`) when `ko.applyBindings` runs. Assuming `editContact` does not return a function, [the `click` binding will then be ignored](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/45e86bf0347cf742ca359bab051ea82fdfae7a5d/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L24).

If you pass `$root.editContact` without calling it, knockout will call it on click with two parameters: the current object (`$data`), and the click event.

```
data-bind="click: $root.editContact"
```

If your `editContact` requires `this` to refer to `$root`, you can use `.bind`:

```
data-bind="click: $root.editContact.bind($root)"
```